# What is correct entry to Input Location (GPFeatureRecordSetLayer)*?

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing, gps, wps

I use:

http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Network/ESRI_DriveTime_US/GPServer/CreateDriveTimePolygons/execute

What is correct entry to **Input Location (GPFeatureRecordSetLayer)** ?

I try:

```
{"type": "Point","coordinates": [-105.01621,39.57422]}
```

but I get : "Invalid value for parameter 'Input_Location'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example from the [Task parameter properties (REST)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005700000070000000) documentation (reformatted):

```
{ 
    "geometryType" : "esriGeometryPoint",
    "fields":[
          {"name":"Id","type":"esriFieldTypeOID","alias":"Id"},
          {"name":"Name","type":"esriFieldTypeString","alias":"Name"}],
    "spatialReference" : {"wkid" : 4326},
    "features" : [
        {
            "geometry" : {"x" : -104.44, "y" : 34.83, "spatialReference" : {"wkid" : 4326}}, 
            "attributes" : {"Id" : 43,"Name" : "Feature 1"}},
        {
            "geometry" : {"x" : -100.65, "y" : 33.69, "spatialReference" : {"wkid" : 4326}},
            "attributes" : {"Id" : 42,"Name" : "Feature 2"}}]
}
```